# Starting from next major object notation for "service" property will no longer be recognized. Set "service" property directly with service name

Tags: serverless-framework

On a serverless project I get the following deprecation warning :

> Serverless: Deprecation warning: Starting from next major object
> notation for "service" property will no longer be recognized. Set
> "service" property directly with service name.
> More Info: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/deprecations/#SERVICE_OBJECT_NOTATION

My Yaml is :

```
service:
    name: nest
custom:
    version: ${self:service.name}-redDragon
```

How can I fix this deprecation warning ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can fix it by setting the name of the service directly to `service` property like this

```
service: nest
custom:
    version: ${self:service.name}-redDragon
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70018281/16620939

This seems to result in the following error:

```
- Cannot resolve variable at "resources.3.Resources.IamRoleLambdaExecution.Properties.RoleName": Value not found at "self" source
```

When setting:

```
LambdaFunctionNamePrefix: ${self:provider.stage}-${self:service.name}
```

Comment: Use ${self:service} for referencing the service's name .

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while, but if you're running a recent version of serverless...

```
service: nest
custom:
  version: ${self:service}-example
```

instead of using `self:service.name` , use `self:service` to reference the name of the service.